# Java Spring MVC database exceptions are not fetching

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In my spring project I want to save students information in mysql database.
If there is any error then it will display in jsp page within corresponding input box.

so,I have:-

**StudentDao** class

```
public interface StudentDao {
    public void add ( Student student );
    }
```

**StudentDaoImpl** class

```
public class StudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

     public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }

    public void add( Student student){
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(student);
    }}
```

**StudentService** class

```
public interface StudentService {
        Student add(String name, String email) throws SQLException, 
                                                   DataAccessException,
                                                   DataIntegrityViolationException,
                                                   ConstraintViolationException{
}
```

**StudentServiceImpl** class

```
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {


    @Autowired
    private StudentDao studentDao;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public Student add(String name, String email) throws SQLException, 
                                                   DataAccessException,
                                                   DataIntegrityViolationException,
                                                   ConstraintViolationException{


    Student student = new Student(name,email);
        studentDao.add(student);

        return student;
            }

}
```

**controller** class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doAdd(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student") Student student,BindingResult result,HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,Model model){

        validator.validate(student, result);
         if (result.hasErrors()) {

                return "signup";
            }

                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                Student student1;

                 try{   
                try {
                    student1= studentService.add(student.getName(), student.getEmail());
                } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {

                    model.addAttribute("email", "already exists");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                     return "signup";
                } catch (DataAccessException e) {

                    model.addAttribute("email", "already exists");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                     return "signup";
                } catch (SQLException e) {

                    model.addAttribute("email", "already exists");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                     return "signup";
                }
                 }catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) 
                 {
                        model.addAttribute("email", "already exists");

                        e.printStackTrace();
                         return "signup";

                 }

        return "signup";
    }
```

but the problem is in my database email field is unique.so, for duplicate entry I am getting log message:

```
 WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:100 - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
  JDBCExceptionReporter:101 - Duplicate entry 'df@gmail.com' for key 'unique_index2'
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.myweb.model.Student]
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'df@gmail.com' for key 'unique_index2'
```

I want to place this error to jsp view email field that **email already exists**  I used throws block in service class and try-catch block in controller class..though why the error is not showing in jsp view?

Comment: is that the entire stack trace?  Friendly advice: You shouldn't catch all those exceptions in the controller.  You want to do it in the service and then return your own exception, eg ValidationException

Comment: @John Scattergood  can you give any example ?

Answer (score 0):

So, you are using spring with hibernate..
and the exception is: **ConstraintViolationException**
 thats why its:

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException
```

just add:

```
<h1>${email}</h1>
```

you can use other tag to display that message.

Answer (score 0):

Just write below Syntax in **ConstraintViolationException**  not in Ever Exception.

Syntax of  :
 model.addAttribute("**any variable name**", "**Your Message/Value**");

*As you have defined*
  model.addAttribute("email", "already exists");

*So on jsp side*

> you will get email variable message/value  as ${email}

Answer (score 0):

just add
**${email}** el variable in your jsp page.